# primary menu edit in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

WordPress
Theme responsive
I have 5 primary navigation menus below header on my website.Want to have sixth menu in right corner with yellow colour and link url directing to external website.
How to do it?

Comment: Choose Custom links and goto screen option click css class from Show advanced menu properties.  using that class add yellow color.

Comment: Not clear and 2nd part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

goto appearance -> menu -> custom links -> in URL section enter your external link and in LINK TEXT enter menu item name and add to save.

after refresh your browser can see your sixth menu item at the end of your menu then identify the unique id of this menu and change color of that menu by css. thats all